# Prevent Keying Node from erasing Colors similar to KeyColor

Tags: compositing-nodes, chromakey

In 2.79 Blender Internal, the keying node is erasing colors similar to the key color (white) like light blue, pink etc.

Is there any way to covert the exact color (Hex value) alpha?

Tried directly inputing Hex:FFFFFF in the key color but didn't work.

***Original Image***

[image: Original Image]

***Keying Result (feather = 0)***

[image: Keying Result (feather = 0]

***Keying Result (feather = 11)***

[image: Keying Result (feather = 11)]

Comment: Not sure, why this question was downvoted? Played with the despill,feather and blur values of the keying node  but was never able to get any acceptable result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***Color Key Node*** does a fairly good job of generating alpha transparency from a key color.

Simply had to tweak the "value" slider for the key color and got the result.

An additional blur node was added to soften the rough edges.

[image: color node]